# Angular.js - Correct way of handing data used in multiple locations

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to set up a relatively simple online shopping app in Angular.js.

I use the ng-route module to show an item-list view and an item-detail view. When loading the item-list route, I use resolve to load a json file with the list of items (description, image url, price, etc.).

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/items', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/item-list.html',
            controller: 'ItemListController',
            resolve: {
                items: ["Item", function(Item) {
                    return Item.fetch();
                }]
            }
        }).
        when('/items/:itemID', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/item-detail.html',
            controller: 'ItemDetailController',
            resolve: {
                dish: ["$route", "Item", function($route, Item) {
                    return Item.fetch($route.current.params.itemID);
                }]
            }
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/items'
        });
}]);
```

I have also created a Cart service to handle adding/removing items to the shopping cart.

```
services.factory("Cart", function() {
    return {
        add: function(item) {
            ...
        },
        remove: function(item) {
            ...
        }
        items: ...
    }
});
```

This shopping cart is loaded/saved to a cookie (is this best practice?). Only the itemID of the items are saved to a cookie. When the shopping cart is reloaded from the cookies, I would like to fetch the items again from the server (in case the description or price would have changed). It seems unefficient to perform another http query here to load the items (as a request is already performed by the router when loading the item-list route). What is the best practice for this?

Comment: Why would there be another http query. Doesn't Item.fetch() do the job the first time? Why would you need to get them again?

Comment: There would be a second fetch to load the item details after loading the current shopping cart from the cookie

Comment: Well if you are loading all the information that is associated to the items when you get the list of them and then you want to re-get the information from the server to make sure its up to date, there isn't really another simple alternative to doing that. 
its a common approach to show a listing of data, and then get more data for a specific record of that data.

Answer (score 0):

A quick-win solution would be to create a service that contains the shopping cart.

This service can use angular's '$cache/$cacheFactory' to keep it in memory. By the way, I think it's better to use memory (for small data), session storage (for bigger data) and local storage (for data you want to keep between sessions). That's way better then cookies.

As you can see on Wishtack.com, there's no cookie at all.

By the way, on Wishtack.com, we use a custom module (that we'll release soon on github.com) on top "restangular" (you should use it instead of $http) that handles cache etc... and uses objects so we can make calls like:

```
CartProduct.all().getListLazy();
```

so the lazy call will try to get the value from the cache instead of calling server every time.

Meanwhile we release the module, you can simply use a service like this:

```
(function () {

/* We use dejavu for classes as we hate functions at Wishtack :). */
var User = dejavu.Class.declare({

    _productList: null,

    initialize: function initialize(args) {
        ... load cart using "args.userId" ...
    },

    cartProductList: function cartProductList() {
        ... or load it here lazily ...

        return this._productList;
    }

});

yourModule.factory('User', function () {

    return User;

});

})();
```

and use it this way.

```
function (User) {
    new User({userId: userId}).cartProductList();
}
```